# Lenovo wifi connection disconects after a while (rtl8723be)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless

**Environment:**

- Wifi network rtl8723be
- Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- Kernel 3.16.0-50-generic

PROBLEM: wifi network disconnects after a while of being working properly.

```
$ sudo lshw -short
/0/100/1c.1/0   wlan0        network        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a easiest solution to make it work.

We need to modify the default options by creating or modifying a file that provide options for the kernel module that governs the Wireless card.

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Add the following text:

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=0
```

Now to take effect the realtek module options, we need to reboot.

After you restart your host, the wireless connection should be stable and solid, and you should achieve good downloads.

We can check the details of the options by running

```
modinfo rtl8723be
```

This will tell you about various power saving options.